# Docker "share" Container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, nfs

I'd like to share some files via a Docker container, but I'm not sure how. I have a project that has several scripts in it. I also have several VMs that need access to those scripts, and especially the latest versions. I'd like to build a docker container that has those scripts inside of it, and then have my VMs be able to mount the container and access the scripts. I tried https://hub.docker.com/r/erichough/nfs-server/ and "baking" the files in, but I don't think that does what I want it to do. Here is the docker file:

```
FROM erichough/nfs-server:latest

COPY ./Scripts /etc/exports/

EXPOSE 2049
```

It fails saying that I need to define /etc/exports. Looking at the entrypoint.sh it wants exports to be a file, so I'm guessing paths inside. So I tried creating an exports.txt file that has the path of my files:

exports.txt:

`./Scripts`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM erichough/nfs-server:latest

ADD ./exports.txt /etc/exports

EXPOSE 2049
```

No bueno. Is there a way to accomplish this? My end goal is a docker container in my registry that I can run in my stack. Whenever I update the scripts I push a new container.

Comment: Can the scripts run in the context of a docker container?

Comment: You cannot extract the scripts out of a Docker image and run them; if that's your high-level goal then using a tar file or a general-purpose system-management tool like Ansible or Salt Stack might be a better match.  Syntactically your first approach seems right except that `/etc/exports` is typically a _file_, not a directory, and it's a control file for the NFS server and not specifically stuff to be published; you'd put the file content somewhere else.